# I have an error pointing to this block class but i'm not sure what's wrong with it.. (magento 2.2.5)

Tags: magento2, layout, blocks, xml, magento-2.2.5

A validation error occured in an XML layout file

```
<block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="gbp_success_page-block">
```

---

```
        <container name="gbp-fullwidth-hero-wrapper" as="heroWrapper" label="Hero Wrapper" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="gbp-fullwidth-hero-wrapper" before="main.content">
          <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="gbp-fullwidth-hero-block" ifconfig="theme/general/enable_fullwidth_hero">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">gbp_fullwidth_hero</argument>
            </arguments>
          </block>
        </container>
```

I do not see anything wrong with this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> <body> <referenceContainer name="content"> <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="gbp_success_page-block"> <arguments> <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">gbp_success_page</argument> </arguments> </block> </referenceContainer> </body>
```

Comment: what is the error , could you share the screenshot or complete error message ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can you try this?

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceContainer name="content"> 
        <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="gbp_success_page-block">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">gbp_success_page</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
    </referenceContainer>
</body>
</page>
```

Comment: correct, i was missing this line.

Comment: <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">